# SQL with if else

Tags: sql

I am struggling to write a sql query where the scenario is as such that -
I have two records for the same policy(say "abc") and I have to return only one based on a condition:

```
                Id policy status 
                33 abc    active 
                15 abc    active
```

If the record with id 15 is present and is in active status for policy "abc" then only this record should be returned. But if the record 15 is not present or in inactive status then the other active record should be returned.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Show the code you wrote to attempt to solve this.

Comment: Hi I was trying switch case statement which did not work at all.I am using MicrosoftSql 2014.However solutions given below worked big thanks.

Comment: Also I tried this -                                                                                                                                                  select branchid 
  if exists(select branchid from POLICY where policyNumbr = '123' and id='15' and AccountStatus='Active')
  begin
  select branchid from POLICY where policyNumbr = '123' and id='15' and AccountStatus='Active'
  end
  else
  select branchid from POLICY where policyNumbr = '123' and AccountStatus='Active'
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous solution does not account for policy, try this

if exists (Select * from tbl where ID = 15 and policy = 'abc' and status = 'active')
    Select * from tbl where ID = 15 and policy = 'abc' and status = 'active'
else 
    Select * from tbl where ID <> 15

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle, then you would use an "exists" statement in your where clause on a self join to verify that a ID 15 exists for that policy

Answer (score 0):

create table my_table (
  id int,
  policy varchar(10),
  status varchar(10)
);
This should work:

```
insert into my_table (id, policy, status) values (33, 'abc', 'active');

insert into my_table (id, policy, status) values (15, 'abc', 'active');

select * from my_table where id = 15 and status = 'active'
union 
select * from my_table where id = 33 and not exists (
  select * from my_table where id = 15 and status = 'active'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the 15 active, otherwise the 33 active if 15 doesn't exist.  It's inferred you only care about 'active' status for a particular policy 'abc'.

As it turns out you can use MIN aggregation for the ID.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, policy, status
  FROM yourtablename
 WHERE status = 'active'
 GROUP BY policy, status
```

Which returns the MIN(ID) for a policy's active statuses.